# await does not wait for Promise to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promises

In my LWC, I am trying to call an Apex method and wait for it to finish. This is what it comes down to:

```
import apexMethodA from '@salesforce/apex/SomeControllerClass.apexMethodA';

export default class TradeWindow extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    initialJSfunction() {
        console.log('about to call waitForApexMethodA');
        this.waitForApexMethodA();
        console.log('finished calling waitForApexMethodA');
        
        // More processing depending on the output of apexMethodA.
    }

    async waitForApexMethodA() {
        console.log('about to call apexMethodA');
        try {
            await apexMethodA();
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('finished calling apexMethodA');
        
        // Some more processing.
    }
}
```

To my surprise/horror, this is what the console log shows:

```
about to call waitForApexMethodA
about to call apexMethodA
finished calling waitForApexMethodA
finished calling apexMethodA
```

This is not what I expected and definitely not what I want. I have read lots of documentation about this and I had hoped that `await` would have the code wait until the Apex method returns with an answer, but apparently that is not how it works.

When I read [Mozilla's documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), it seems that `await` does not wait at all:

> An await splits execution flow, allowing the caller of the async
> function to resume execution.

But in many other places, I read that `await` and `async` are the way to go.

My code is too complicated to solve this with a chain of .then's, I would like to solve it using `await`. How can I do that?

I tried to wrap the call to `waitForApexMethodA` in a Promise and `await` that, but of course, that doesn't work: as soon as `await` is encountered in `waitForApexMethodA`, control is returned to the caller. That is not what I want, `initialJSfunction` should only get control after all of `waitForApexMethodA` has completely finished.

Comment: You're missing an `await` before `this.waitForApexMethodA();`

Comment: @SachinHooda You cannot mark a code line with `await`, if the function/ method is not marked as `async`

Comment: @arut `waitForApexMethodA` is already marked async.

Comment: @SachinHooda `await` operator can only be used inside an `async` function, failing this would throw a runtime error as "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function". The line that is marked with `await` should be inside an `async` function. So, `initialJSfunction` would also have to be marked as `async`.

Comment: correct I missed that!

Comment: This is standard for asynchronous events in JavaScript. `async` functions *always* return a `Promise` which is *not* guaranteed to be resolved before the function returns (although it typically will if and only if its actual execution contains no `await` calls). You need to propagate the usage of `async`/`await` or promises up through all functions which need to await completion of asynchronous operations, directly or indirectly. Without this, what you're suggesting you would require synchronous operations, which require full suspension of the main thread and would be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to the other answerers and commenters. If I modify stackasaur's answer to this:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('2 seconds');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
function resolveAfter4Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('4 seconds');
    }, 4000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result2 = await resolveAfter4Seconds();
  console.log(result2);
  const result1 = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result1);
}

(async function(){
await asyncCall();
console.log('test');
})();
```

then the output will be:

```
calling
4 seconds
2 seconds
test
```

which is exactly what I want. Because of the complexity of my complete JS controller code (about 1200 LOC), I had trouble applying it to my situation.

Answer (score 4):

So it's a bit weird. The "waiting" happens within that aync function, not your initial js function.

consider this example

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('2 seconds');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
function resolveAfter4Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('4 seconds');
    }, 4000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result2 = await resolveAfter4Seconds();
  console.log(result2);
  const result1 = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result1);
}

asyncCall();
console.log('test');
```

The output of this would be

```
> "calling"
> "test"
> "4 seconds"
> "2 seconds"
```

Note that 4 seconds happens before 2, indicating that the `await` did in fact work here; however, 'test' was still printed out first.
It is essentially the same as stringing promises together as you mentioned, just cleaner.

Comment: I guess I have to introduce my own Promise, which will call asyncCall, and then do an await on that before console.log('test') ?

Comment: I'd say rather than having `waitForApexMethodA` just have `asyncMethods` where you do all of the apex calls dependent on each other, then in `initialJSFunction` you'd just call that one function. But know that function would not do the waiting.

Comment: Here is a good example of this being done with multiple apex calls within LWC https://medium.com/@marcoalmodova/lwc-and-async-functions-1d6440080b01

Comment: Wrapping the call in a Promise and doing another await does indeed not help, control is returned to the caller after the first await. How hard can it be to call a function and just wait for its completion?

Comment: in my example, after `resolveAfter4seconds()` is called, the next code is not executed until it finishes. Meaning const result2 is assigned before we proceed

Comment: It is not possible to have all the Apex methods called by one JS function. First one Apex method is called, after that more JS processing plus another Apex method, etc. I guess I will have to restructure my controller (a big big JS object).

Comment: You can also try stringing wire adapters by having the parameters watched and dependent on the next wire adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the `initialJSfunction` as `async` and the method call inside it with `await`. This would make the JS code wait until apex method execution is completed. So, your code snippet would be as shown below:

```
async initialJSfunction() {
    console.log('about to call waitForApexMethodA');
    await this.waitForApexMethodA();
    console.log('finished calling waitForApexMethodA');
    
    // More processing depending on the output of apexMethodA.
}
```

Note that marking a JS method as `async` doesn't really make it asynchronous, unless there are statements within the method marked with `await`. So, if you have any synchronous code execution in the `initialJSfunction` to be executed before apex method call, you would need to have it before the statement marked with `await`. Also, as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/get_started_supported_javascript), too much usage of async-await could lead to performance issues, so use it with some due-diligence.

You could also do a mix of `async-await` & `.then` construct as shown in the snippet below:

```
initialJSfunction() {
    console.log('about to call waitForApexMethodA');
    this.waitForApexMethodA().then((data) => {
         console.log('finished calling waitForApexMethodA');
   
         // More processing depending on the output of apexMethodA.
    });

    // Some synchronous code here if you want some processing before the apex method execution completes
}
```

Comment: If you read the last paragraph in my question, you'll see that I have already tried that. And it doesn't help. As soon as the first await is encountered, control is returned to the caller. The called function is still executed, but the calling function has already gone ahead.

Comment: @SanderdeJong The last paragraph in your question didn't really give me a clear picture about the your actual code. Although I get what you have tried, I wasn't sure about your code. Anyways, I did not actually try the second code snippet given in my answer. But the first code snippet will work without any issues. Are you facing the problem with the first code snippet too?

Comment: No, the first will not work either. waitForApexMethodA will return control to the caller as soon as it encounters its first await. So the console log will show 'finished calling waitForApexMethodA' before 'finished calling apexMethodA'. The only thing that the await does is ensure that the remainder of waitForApexMethodA waits until apexMethodA has finished. But it will not halt execution of the caller.

Comment: Scratch that last remark, upon altering stackasaur's answer I managed to get the order of execution that I want. I guess I was confused by the results of my own JS controller, which is apparently too complex.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Okay, so my first code snippet will work correctly. I believe my second code snippet should work fine too if you carefully fix your existing code. I did just give it a try after your comment and it works fine for me.